# Как конвертировать во float/int столбцы в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-4bSh0Sv9Wt3rhJEFF78OnSVW2mr_BtN/view?usp=sharing

Из датасета пытаюсь конвертировать столбцы

```
df['СуммаОборот'] = df['СуммаОборот'].str.replace(',', ".").astype(float)
```

получаю ошибку

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4\xa0290.32'
```

Как конвертировать во float или int?

Comment: у вас число с разделителем разрядов (пробелом). его тоже удалите, а потом конвертируйте.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['СуммаОборот'] = df['СуммаОборот'].replace(r'\s+','',regex=True)
df['СуммаОборот'] = df['СуммаОборот'].str.replace(',', ".").astype(float)
```

Comment: Там у вас \xa0 - это специальный пробел, удалось его через шаблон \s удалить?